# How to set specific values in a text field?

Tags: java, sql

I was wondering how to put the user only type words I want? for example in the text field it can only type high, medium and low if it is different than not registering in the system does anyone know?

running Mysql, Eclipse

Comment: Consider using a selectbox with 3 items.

Comment: Is it JavaFX or Java Swing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply do that you can choose a combo box where you can put the values for user choose. If you still want this in a text field validation. Try below method.

```
String name = namefield.getText()

if(name.equals("Low") || name.equals("Medium") || name.equals("High")){
      //Proceed Code
}else{
      //Not Matched
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm using JoptionPane so I need

Comment: Does my answer worked ?

Comment: Yes man, thanks a lot helped but I need to do a summation of values now know how to do that? in case the price with full price

Comment: could you mark my answer as correct ? It will help others too..

Comment: sure man but you can help me now?

Comment: I couldn’t understand your second question

Comment: i wanna make a register right for exemple the price of the first product in the final will add with the last product in the of the list